# Функция отправка сообщения

Tags: php

Всем Привет!
У меня на сайте есть бот, который автоматом отвечает и в нем стоит функция отправки сообщения:

```
function processMessage($message) { 
    $message = mb_strtolower($message);

    if ($message === 'hi' || $message === 'hello' || $message === '/start') {
        return 'Hi, I am a bot . What status you want ?? For example: Love, Joke, about life, friendship';
    } elseif ($message === 'love' || $message === 'about love' || $message === '/love') {   
        $statuses = file('telegram_love.txt');
        $status_id = array_rand($statuses);
        return trim($statuses[$status_id]);
     } elseif ($message === 'joke' || $message === 'about joke' || $message === '/joke') {  
        $statuses = file('telegram_joke.txt');
        $status_id = array_rand($statuses);
        return trim($statuses[$status_id]);     
     } elseif ($message === 'life' || $message === 'about life' || $message === '/life') {  
        $statuses = file('telegram_life.txt');
        $status_id = array_rand($statuses);
        return trim($statuses[$status_id]);
     } elseif ($message === 'friendship' || $message === 'about friendship' || $message === '/friendship') {    
        $statuses = file('telegram_friendship.txt');
        $status_id = array_rand($statuses);
        return trim($statuses[$status_id]);
     } elseif ($message === 'about' || $message === '/about' || $message === '/info') { 
        return "v 1.0 Developer Mail
   @mail
                      @mail";
    } else {
        return 'Or we do not have such type of status, or you make a mistake, use the fast function to find the statuses';
    }
}
```

Скрипт берет ответ с файла .txt и я хочу сделать так чтобы ответы взял с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ!

Если не сложно подскажите с чего начать ???  Заранее всем спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенести все сообщения из файлов в базу данных с примерно такой структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `messages` (`id`, `tag`, `message`) VALUES
(1, 'love', 'Love message 1'),
(2, 'love', 'Love message 2'),
(3, 'love', 'Love message 3'),
(4, 'joke', 'Joke message 1'),
(5, 'joke', 'Joke message 2'),
(6, 'joke', 'Joke message 3'),
(7, 'life', 'Life message 1'),
(8, 'life', 'Life message 2'),
(9, 'life', 'Life message 3'),
(10, 'friendship', 'Friendship message 1'),
(11, 'friendship', 'Friendship message 2'),
(12, 'friendship', 'Friendship message 3'),
(13, 'hi', 'Hi, I am a bot . What status you want ?? For example: Love, Joke, about life, friendship'),
(14, 'hello', 'Hi, I am a bot . What status you want ?? For example: Love, Joke, about life, friendship'),
(15, 'start', 'Hi, I am a bot . What status you want ?? For example: Love, Joke, about life, friendship'),
(16, 'about', 'v 1.0 Developer Name\r\n      @mail\r\n                         @mail'),
(17, 'info', 'v 1.0 Developer Name\r\n      @mail\r\n                         @mail');
```

И в функции сделать выбор сообщения по тегу из этой таблицы

```
function processMessage($message, $db_link)
{
    $message = mb_strtolower($message);
    $message = str_replace('about ', '', $message);
    $message = trim($message, ' /');

    $q = "SELECT `message` "
        ."FROM `messages` "
        ."WHERE `tag`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link, $message)."' "
        ."ORDER BY RAND() "
        ."LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($db_link, $q);
    if ($res)
    {
        $status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $status = $status['message'];
    }
    else
    {
        $status = 'Or we do not have such type of status, or you make a mistake, use the fast function to find the statuses';
    }

    return $status;
}
```

Использование:

```
$db_link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'пользователь', 'пароль', 'имя базы') or die(mysqli_connect_error());

echo processMessage('about life', $db_link);
```

Comment: а как же `PDO`?

Comment: так же, как и mysqli

Comment: что?))) Почему не используешь класс для работы с бд? уже готовый, отлично работающий?

Comment: ну можно и через PDO сделать, конечно, но автор спрашивает "с чего начать?", потому я решил что проще показать пример на mysqli

Comment: Darevill, Спасибо вам!